# C# Sentence count function - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'int'

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a sentence count function but i face the following error.
What should i change the datatype to?

```
private int SplitSentences(string fbStatus)
        {
            int splitSentences = Regex.Split(fbStatus, @"(?<=['""A-Za-z0-9][\.\!\?])\s+(?=[A-Z])");
            label_totalsentencecount.Text = splitSentences.ToString();
            return splitSentences;

        }
```

Comment: Have you looked up what type `Regex.Split()` returns?

Comment: Look at the return type of `Regex.Split`. It's `string[]`. You should put it in to an array of strings and then get the `Length` property.

Comment: @John3136 - Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3):

The method should read

```
private int SplitSentences(string fbStatus)
{
    string[] splitSentences = Regex.Split(fbStatus, @"(?<=['""A-Za-z0-9][\.\!\?])\s+(?=[A-Z])");
    label_totalsentencecount.Text = splitSentences.Length.ToString();
    return splitSentences.Length;
}
```

The type of `splitSentences` is `string[]`, where you want to return the length and not the actual set of sentences.

Comment: ..and yet it is still typed as `int` in your example..

Comment: Heh, missed the one on the first line, corrected for the return, updating. Thanks